# Can not input chinese character into Spyder

Tags: python, ubuntu, spyder

On Ubuntu 16.04 ,I can use sougoupinyin in everywhere else except in python IDE Spyder,I just can not input Chinese characters as comment into spyder. I really don't know how to fix this.

Comment: What version of Spyder IDE are you using?

Comment: I am sorry I haven't made it clear ,I download the spyder together with anaconda 4.4.0, It should be a new version, I don't know exactly,Thank you